# Возможен ли вывод данных из разных json-файлов в item карусели на angular?

Tags: angularjs

На странице, сделанной с angular, при переходе на товар открывается страница, на которой карусель с изначально необходимым товаром.

Товары я получаю не в одном json.

Возможно ли ng-repeat выводить товары из разных json-файлов в зависимости от идентификатора? Или возможно есть куда более простое решение?

КОНТРОЛЛЕР

```
[velesApp.controller('KitchenDetailCtrl',
    ['$scope','$http', '$location', '$routeParams', 
        function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams) {
            $scope.kitchenId = $routeParams.kitchenId;
            var url = 'kitchens/'+$routeParams.kitchenId+'.json';
            $http.get(url).success(function(data) { 
                $scope.kitchendet = data; 
            });
```

HTML

```
<slick ng-repeat="kitchendet in kitchendets ">
<h2 class="text-center"> {{kitchendet.name}}
```

МАРШРУТИЗАЦИЯ

```
.when('/kitchens/:kitchenId', 
{ 
    templateUrl:'template/kitchen-detail.html', 
    controller:'KitchenDetailCtrl' 
})
```

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под _разными джейсонами_?

Comment: каждый товар получаю в отдельном джейсон файле

Comment: несколько вариантов, от загрузки всех товаров, до подгрузки их по нажатию кнопки например. _ng-repeat_ работает только с масивом/объектом который вы ему передали, но вы можете изменять этот массив/объект и _ng-repeat_ обновит html. Для конкретного решения, нужно больше информации, ваш код, как вы храните товары. почему не в списке товаров например?

Comment: вставляйте код в свой вопрос, чтобы его было сразу видно и можно было отформатировать

Comment: и еще html разметку

Comment: перенес код из комментариев в вопрос. Andrey, значимые вещи добавляй в текст вопроса, а не в комментарии

Comment: @AndreyFedorovich, можете простой пример на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) сделать? сейчас не совсем понятно как связаны между собой приведенные куски

Comment: Спасибо, на самом деле я решил с загрузкой всех товаров, просто изначально не понял что вы имели ввиду.

Answer (score 1):

Не правильный подход к реализации, Вам нужно использовать сервис, не самая лучшая реализация но как пример сойдёт мой сервис, а вообще я сейчас через ngresource делаю. В Контроллере останется только проверить пришёл ли ID  если есть то забираем 1 запись из Projects.items если нет данных в items  пробуем загрузить их с сервера. У меня тут post  забирает потому как я ещё параметры передаю для обрезки изображений, в вашем случае достаточно будет get.

```
questServices.factory('Projects', ['$http', '$timeout', 'Upload',
    function ($http, $timeout, Upload) {
        var service = function (editor) {
            this.items = [];
            this.busy = false;
            this.after = '';
            this.page = '';
            this.end = false;
            this.new_project = {};
            this.getClass = 'btn-default';
            this.setdelete = null;
        };


        service.prototype.save = function () {
            if (this.busy)
                return;
            this.busy = true;

            var file = this.new_project.image;
            file.upload = Upload.upload({
                url: '/resource/addproject',
                data: {file: file, project: JSON.stringify(this.new_project)},
            });

            file.upload.then(function (response) {
                this.busy = false;
                console.log(response.data);
                this.new_project = {};
                this.getClass = 'btn-success';
                this.load();
                $timeout(function () {
                    this.getClass = 'btn-default';
                    this.busy = false;
                }.bind(this), 2000);


            }.bind(this), function (response) {
                //this.busy = false;
                //console.log('test');
                //console.log(response.data);
            }, function (evt) {
                // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                console.log(file.progress);
            });


        }


        service.prototype.load = function (params, callback) {
            if (this.busy)
                return;
            this.busy = true;
            var url = "resource/projects";


            $http.post(url, params).
            then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.items = response.data.projects;
                this.busy = false;
                $timeout(function () {
                    if (typeof callback == 'function')
                        callback();
                }.bind(this), 1000);

            }.bind(this), function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });


        };

        service.prototype.delete = function () {
            if (this.busy)
                return;
            this.busy = true;
            var url = "resource/deleteproject/" + this.setdelete.id;
            $http.get(url).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);

                angular.forEach(this.items, function (item, key) {
                    if (item.id == this.setdelete.id) {
                        this.items.splice(key, 1);
                    }
                }.bind(this));


                this.setdelete = null;


                this.busy = false;
            }.bind(this)).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            });
        };


        service.prototype.update = function () {
            if (this.busy)
                return;
            this.busy = true;
            var url = "resource/updateproject";


            var file = this.new_project.image;
            if (file) {
                console.log('Отправил через файл');
                file.upload = Upload.upload({
                    url: url,
                    data: {file: file, project: JSON.stringify(this.new_project)},
                });

                file.upload.then(function (response) {
                    this.busy = false;
                    console.log(response.data);

                    this.getClass = 'btn-success';
                    this.load();
                    $timeout(function () {
                        this.getClass = 'btn-default';
                        this.new_project = {};
                        this.busy = false;
                    }.bind(this), 2000);


                }.bind(this), function (response) {
                    //this.busy = false;
                    //console.log('test');
                    //console.log(response.data);
                }, function (evt) {
                    // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
                    file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                    console.log(file.progress);
                });
            } else {
                $http.post(url, {project: JSON.stringify(this.new_project)}).
                then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.getClass = 'btn-success';
                    $timeout(function () {
                        this.getClass = 'btn-default';
                        this.busy = false;
                    }.bind(this), 2000);
                }.bind(this), function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }


        };


        return service;
    }
]);
```